# Word - How can I increase the distance between pages?

Tags: microsoft-word

[image: C]]

I am trying to crop the photo above, but the page underneath is blocking some of the image. How can I increase the distance the pages are separated from one another?

Comment: Best option is to right-click the image and go to `Size & Position` then reduce the size down so it fits on the page.

Comment: The image should be cropped in an image editor like paint.net and not inside Word.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see the whole image if you temporarily switch to "*Web Layout*" - the button is in the bottom right hand corner.

[image: layout options]

Once you're done, you can switch back to "*Print Layout*" which is the view you are currently in.

Alternatively, temporarily set the height and/or width so that the image fits on the page:

[image: image size tools]